# Convert a file into a list with integers

Tags: list, python-2.7

```
 with open('askhsh11.txt', 'r') as f:
 raw_list =  f.read().split('\n')

for i in range(len(raw_list)):
  print raw_list[i].split(',')

for i in range(len(raw_list)):  
  raw_list[i]=int(i)
  print raw_list
```

the result is :

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['5', '6', '7', '8']
[0, '5,6,7,8']
[0, 1]
```

but i want the result to be:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['5', '6', '7', '8']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

How i convert a list of strings into a integers?

Comment: `print map(int, raw_list[i].split(','))`

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
result = [int(c) for s in  raw_list for c in s.split(',')]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just replace the "'" character to remove them

```
with open('askhsh11.txt', 'r') as f:
    raw_list =  f.read().replace("'","").split('\n')

numbers = [int(num) for num in raw_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honnest . i'm biginner in this langage . but i can tell you that you can use the 2 first output to generate the 2 second output .
what i mean that  it's easy to convert

```
this :
['1', '2', '3', '4']
to this :
[1, 2, 3, 4] .
```

just use the function that  convert the string like '1' to the integer 1 .

sorry i gorget its name but u find it on python support 
for evryone who know the function's name .plz make a comment and thank you so much